# stripping a text from a form

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is the input form code

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td align="right" class="innertablestyle"><font class="normal"><strong>Homepage</strong></font></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <font class='normal'>
            http://
            <input name="website" type="text" id="website" value="<?php echo $website; ?>">
            &nbsp;
        </font>
        <font class="normal">&nbsp; </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the display code

```
<tr > 
<td height="25" class="selllink"> Website 
Address<font class="h2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

<?php 
$group_set=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from b2b_groups where sb_memtype=".$mem["sb_memtype"])); 
if(($sbrow_off["sb_website"]<>"")&&($group_set["sb_posturl"]=='yes')) 
{echo "<a href='http://".$sbrow_off["sb_website"]."' target='_blank'>".$sbrow_off["sb_website"]."</a>"; } 
else 
{echo $config["sb_null_char"];} 
?> 
</font></td> 
</tr>
```

form that collects url of users to store in a database. They should not enter the http:// with their URL however many and the result is that when their url is displayed it looks like this

http;//http://www.foo.com I need the form to strip it or ignore it or what ever you think is the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (stripos($website, "http://") === 0) 
    $website = substr($website, 7);
```